# multiple line inputs in C

Tags: c, line, stdin

I have to do the following things for my project
eg given an input such as

```
9 3 2 5
6 3 4 6 1
9 5 0 4 3 1
```

I will need to do the following things

i)divide the input in separate sets according to each line such as

```
set1={9,3,2,5)
set2={6,3,4,6,1}
set3={9,5,0,4,3,1}
```

ii)I will also need the individual elements in each set(such as 9,3,2,5 in set 1) as integers for further processing

notes:I am not allowed to give the input in a separate file so I tried entering as 
"9 3 2 5\n6 3 4 6 1\n9 5 0 4 3 1"as pressing the enter after each line won't do as I will be required to give the full input in one go

Also I am required to use ONLY C

Any ideas to implement the above will be appreciated
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you limited to any specific version of the C Standard?

Comment: I don't understand your “notes” about not using the ENTER key.  Your C program doesn't care how you've created the bytes you feed it as input.  Simply write your lines of numbers into a text file and give it to your program as input.

Comment: You need to make some attempt at this and ask questions about where you get stuck.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions. Please be aware that we do not provide _from-stratch_ coding service here. :-)

Comment: Is there an known upper limit on the number of "sets" to be read?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `fgets()` to read the lines, and then `strtok()` to parse each line, this is a sample program, i've used the first element of the integer array as the array count, so you don't need to store it in a separate variable, I did that because I assume you can have different length arrays.

```
int freeArray(int **array, int setCount)
{
    if (array == NULL)
        return 0;
    while (setCount > 0)
        free(array[--setCount]);
    free(array);

    return -1;
}

void printArray(int *const *const array, int setCount)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0 ; i < setCount ; ++i)
    {
        const int *pointer;
        int        j;

        pointer = array[i];
        if (pointer == NULL)
            continue;
        for (j = 1 ; j <= pointer[0] ; j++)
            printf("%d ", pointer[j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int *parseLine(char *line, int setCount)
{
    char *pointer;
    int   count;
    char *token;
    int  *array;

    while ((*line != '\0') && (isspace(*line) != 0))
        line++;
    if (*line == '\0')
        return NULL;

    array   = NULL;
    pointer = line;
    count   = 0;

    while ((token = strtok(pointer, " ")) != NULL)
    {
        char *endptr;
        void *tmp;

        pointer  = NULL;
        tmp = realloc(array, (1 + ++count) * sizeof(int));
        if (tmp == NULL)
        {
            free(array);
            return NULL;
        }
        array        = tmp;
        array[0]     = count;
        array[count] = strtol(token, &endptr, 10);

        if ((*endptr != '\0') && ((*endptr != '\n')))
            fprintf(stderr, "error: the %dth %s: value of the %dth line, is not an integer\n",
                                                                count, token, setCount);
    }
    return array;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char  line[256];
    int **array;
    int   setCount;

    line[0]  = '\0';
    array    = NULL;
    setCount = 0;
    while (line[0] != '\n')
    {
        void *tmp;

        if (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) == NULL)
            return -1;

        tmp = realloc(array, (1 + setCount) * sizeof(int *));
        if (tmp == NULL)
            return freeArray(array, setCount);

        array           = tmp;
        array[setCount] = parseLine(line, setCount);
        if (array[setCount] != NULL)
            setCount += 1;
    }
    printArray(array, setCount);
    freeArray(array, setCount);

    return 0;
}
```

at the end I show you how to access the elements of the array of arrays by printing them, and also how to `free` the `malloc`ed memory.

This program will exit when you press enter, but if you type a space before pressing enter, there will be problems, I'll let you think about a solution to that.